# Перенаправление вида http://www.itoil.ru/***/index.php -> http://www.itoil.ru/***/ в чем ошибка?

Tags: mod_rewrite, php

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  ^/([^/]+)/index.php http://www.itoil.ru/$1/index.php [R]
```

Comment: @Артамонов_Павел, уточните, чего вы хотели добиться?  
Сделать редирект с `/index.php` на версию без `index.php`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно убрать слэш сразу после первого символа ^

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/index.php http://www.itoil.ru/$1/index.php [R]
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно Вы забыли убрать 'index.php' в строке замены.

```
RewriteRule  ([^/]+)/index.php$ /$1/ [R,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Пишет циклическое перенаправление.

Options +FollowSymLinks

ErrorDocument 401 /ru/errors/401/
ErrorDocument 403 /ru/errors/403/
ErrorDocument 404 /ru/errors/404/
ErrorDocument 500 /ru/errors/500/

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.it-oil.ru
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.itoil.ru/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^www\.]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?.*/index.php$
#RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/index.php$ http://www.itoil.ru/$1/ [R=301,L]

Comment: #News rewrite rule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}ru%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/ru/news/([^\.]+)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/news/([^\.]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ news/index.php?id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

#Main rewrite rule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ru/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}ru/$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]